# How can I change the Viewport Display Color of a material with Python?

Tags: python, materials

I am trying to create a script that resets the viewport display color of all selected objects that have a material. I'm talking about this value:

[image: Display Color]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Code to toggle viewport display material alpha](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199455/code-to-toggle-viewport-display-material-alpha/199469#199469)

Comment: If you have Developers extras enabled in the preferences you just have to hover your mouse over the field to know the path of the property. It's called `diffuse_color`

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Got it working.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. Otherwise, just let me know.