# Add custom hotkey for existing addon fuction in the keymap editor

Tags: python, add-on

An addon I installed has a button in the interface with an associated function, and the button doesn't have a hotkey. When I hover over the button, there's a python tooltip with the function, something like "bpy.ops.addonName.functionName(arguments)"

How do I add a new custom hotkey that mimics a press of that button, running the associated function and arguments, through the keymap editor in Blender settings?

Comment: Related or dupe: [Create keyboard shortcut for an operator using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196518/31447)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the button, and use "assign shortcut":

[image]

It will be saved in your settings and available for the next sessions.