# Scripting about properties panel

Tags: scripting

When my mouse in properties panel, How can I create a shortcut such that when I press 'FIVE' then toggle to modifier panel.[image]

Blender Ver: 2.91

Comment: Please in future use text to paste script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`bpy.ops.wm.context_set_enum(...)`**

Setting a value from a context path for a shortcut use one of the `bpy.ops.wm.context_set`... operators

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.context_set_
                           boolean(
                           enum(
                           float(
                           id(
                           int(
                           string(
                           value(
```

This one is an enum property (string would work too)

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.context_set_enum(
context_set_enum()
bpy.ops.wm.context_set_enum(data_path="", value="")
Set a context value
```

For the equivalent to

```
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'MODIFIERS'
```

using an operator will be,

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_set_enum(
        datapath="space_data.context",
        value='MODIFIERS',
        )
```

cannot test this in python console because it is not in the correct properties space context, instead add it manually to test, *`Edit > Preferences > Keymaps > Properties Edit`*

[image]

...Ok numpad 5 now switches to modifiers tab.

To set up shortcut using python see

[Create keyboard shortcut for an operator using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/create-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-operator-using-python)*

Comment: Thank you very much, I click those "small" icons lot of times every day, realy need this solution.