# KeyMaps for TEXT_EDITOR doesnt wor'k for 3.5?

Tags: interface, shortcut

[Answer from here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237663/76629) works great. But when I try it with Script Editor no combinations work.

I changed

```
IMAGE_EDITOR
```

to

```
TEXT_EDITOR
```

Am I missing something?

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "image.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Image Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, "called")
        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager # handle the keymap
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Image', space_type='TEXT_EDITOR')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
            SimpleOperator.bl_idname, type='Y', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently name has to be changed to "Text" too:

```
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Text', space_type='TEXT_EDITOR')
```