# Keyboard shortcut set using python disappears when blender is reopened

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shortcut

I set a blender shortcut for a custom operator in my addon using the code described here: [Create keyboard shortcut for an operator using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/create-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-operator-using-python)

When I install the addon the shortcut is registered and works fine. But when I close and reopen blender the shortcut has disappeared from the keymap in edit > preferences. However, the addon is still activated. When I deactivate and reactivate the addon the shortcut reappears and it works. How do I make the shortcut stay?

I tried using the code in the link above instead of my own code as a test and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Do you have auto-save set for preferences? Otherwise, you have to also save your preferences in python, or the shortcut won't appear.

Comment: Yes I have auto-save enabled. It works fine when I first install the addon and then stops working when I reopen blender. I also tried enabling auto-save within the python script but that did not work.

Comment: I suppose you could force the preference save with `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()`  If that doesn't work, then perhaps the code you're using is broken, although it looks OK to me at a first glance.